# Generate and store freq tables for every variables in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
set.seed(6)
df <- data.frame(a=floor(runif(100)*5),b=floor(runif(100)*4),c=floor(runif(100)*3))
```

I want to produce summary freq tables for every variable and store them in one dataset. For example.

```
outexample <- rbind(table(df$a),c(table(df$b),0),c(table(df$c),0,0))
rownames(outexample) <- letters[1:3]
outexample

   0  1  2  3  4
a 19 18 20 18 25
b 30 23 19 28  0
c 28 33 39  0  0
```

There are hundreds of variables and unknown number of classes in each variable. Is there a more decent way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stack()` and `table()` - and `t()` to get desired output.

```
t(table(stack(df)))
#   values
#ind  0  1  2  3  4
#  a 19 18 20 18 25
#  b 30 23 19 28  0
#  c 28 33 39  0  0
```

---

With `data.table` you do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dcast(data = melt(df), variable ~ value)
```

Answer (score 2):

This makes it long, then counts, then widens it again

```
library(magrittr)
df %>% 
  tidyr::gather(variable, score) %>% 
  dplyr::count(variable, score) %>% 
  tidyr::spread(score, n, fill=0)
```

results

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  variable   `0`   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a           19    18    20    18    25
2 b           30    23    19    28     0
3 c           28    33    39     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also `unlist` the dataset and apply the `table` by replicating the column names

```
table(rep(names(df), each = nrow(df)), unlist(df))

#     0  1  2  3  4    
#  a 19 18 20 18 25
#  b 30 23 19 28  0
#  c 28 33 39  0  0
```